# Backbone-relational with Django

Tags: django, backbone.js

I'm building a Backbonejs app that is running Django in the backend. In my Django, i have models like `Author`, `books`, `shelf` and `user` and they are related to one another. In Backbone, I have a model `Author` and when I do a `fetch()` I get its related models in an array. Should I proceed like this or it's better to create the same models in Backbone and do the same relations between them? (with backbone-relational)
Also, let's say I go with the second option, when i do `fetch()` and get related models, shall backbone-relational recognize it directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend leveraging Backbone relational--especially if you expect the app to get somewhat complex later.

Probably you won't have to change your server side code, you can get Backbone relational to instantiate any related models that are included in the JSON of the model you have fetched.  So if for an author query your backend returns:

```
[{
    name: "Hemingway, Ernest", 
    books: [
         {name: "For whom the bell tolls", ISBN: 1234},
         {name: "The sun also rises", ISBN: 2345}
    ]
}]
```

... and you have defined a has-many relationship between Authors and books Backbone relational will instantiate the books as well.